# PHP class method arguments declaration

Tags: php, function, class, arguments

```
class myClass {
   function myFunct(Foo $var) {
      ...
   }

   function otherFunct(myClass $other) {
        ...
   }
}
```

I've seen this declaration couple times in php manual however i dont get it, in this particular example what purpose it serving to have `Foo` and/or `myClass` in arguments list for a function?

Is there any use for this declaration outside of class?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind i found it called type declaration (type hints)
http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration